# Have well directly connect or touch the navbar in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/snapapps/pen/aepGs)

I am trying to have the well directly "connect", or touch the navbar. I tried resetting the padding to 0px, to no avail. How could I do this? *See CodePen*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.navbar` has a `margin-bottom: 20px` which you need to remove. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HDRap/)